# Why does elif execute one statement among many without syntax error

Tags: python

This is my second week learning Python. The code I wrote below works up to 1968. Anything beyond 1968 for instance 1971 gives the same result between 1965 and 1968 of 6000. Can  anyone help to explain the cause for this.

```
year =  int(input('Enter year: '))
while year: 
   if year < 1962:
      print('Car did not exist yet!')
      print('Please enter a valid year after 1962')
   elif year <= 1964:
      print('$18500')
   elif year >= 1965 <= 1968:
      print('$6000')
   elif year >= 1969 <= 1971:
      print('$12000')
   elif year >= 1972 <= 1975:
      print('$48000')
   elif year >= 1976 <= 1980:
      print('$200000')
   elif year >= 1981 <=1985:
      print('$650000')
   elif year >= 1986 <=2012:
      print('$35000000')
   elif year >=2013 <=2014:
      print('$52000000')
   else:
       print('Error Message')
   int(input('Enter year: '))
```

Comment: This: `year >= 1965 <= 1968` doesn't work the way you want it to.

Comment: to clarify, that is equivalent to `year >= 1965 and 1965 <= 1968`, or just `year >= 1965`.

You should write something like `1965 <= year <= 1968`

Comment: You actually don't even need to get that fancy here. You know the year is `>= 1965` or the previous `<= 1964` test would have already captured it, so you can just write `elif year <= 1968`, and the same for all of the subsequent ones.

Comment: Also, an unrelated problem, but just doing `int(input(…))` just gets sme input, converts it to an int, and then throws the result away. You probably wanted to do something with that result, like `year = int(input(…))`.

Comment: One last thing: you may find this easier to do with a loop over a sequence of year-price pairs. By making it data-driven, the code is a bit more complicated, but you only have to get it right once, instead of 9 times, and you can expand on it by letting the user input the model-price data, or reading it from a file, etc. See [this](https://repl.it/repls/AmusingDependentDestination) for a quick example.

Answer (score 1):

`elif year >= 1965 <= 1968` means: `year` is greater than or equal to 1965, and 1965 is less than or equal to 1968.

Since `1965 <= 1968` always, the condition is effectively just `year >= 1965`.

Did you mean

```
elif 1965 <= year <= 1968:
```

?

Comment: Between 1965 and 1968 price was $6000 but I want to have price of 12000 between 1969 and 1971. So may be the operators are wrong. That is where I confused

Answer (score 0):

another solution :
    elif year >= 1969 and year <= 1971: